# Why does it requires me to define a view model as DbSet in DbContext class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to add a Razor view using a template with a model like this:
[image]

It occurs an error When I click add:

[image]

> There was an error running the selected code generator make sure that "dbcontext" has a DbSet property for MovieDetailResponse

As you can see, I had a model named **MovieDetailResponse**, I would not like to add it to my database since I had an entity class **Movie**, which has already been in the database, this is my code:

```
// MovieShopDbContext.cs
 public class MovieShopDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MovieShopDbContext(DbContextOptions<MovieShopDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>(ConfigureMovie);
            
        }
        public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }

        private void ConfigureMovie(EntityTypeBuilder<Movie> builder)
        {
            // specify your Fluent API rules.
            builder.ToTable("Movie");
            //using ValueGeneratedOnAdd check if not using it
            builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);
            builder.Property(m => m.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        }
    }
```

I had an entity class named **Movie**, and a model class named **MovieDetailResponse**, so why does it happen to me? Must I declare `DbSet<MovieDetailResponse>` explicitly in my DbContext class?

Comment: That razor view wizard is assuming you want to bind your view to a data context, in which case you would nominate the DbContext and the Entity to serve as the view model. Personally I always recommend *not* doing this as the view rarely needs to see *everything* about an entity and related entities. If the DataContext selection can remain empty, try just specifying your view model. When viewing and submitting the view you will need to add the code to project your view model and load/transpose your entities.

Comment: @StevePy Can you explain "If the DataContext selection can remain empty, try just specifying your view model. When viewing and submitting the view you will need to add the code to project your view model and load/transpose your entities" a little bit? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Just don't select an entry for "Data context class".   It will mean wiring up your own population for the view model. I wasn't able to test what wiring you have to provide since my projects don't use wizard-generated views and when I tried to create one I just repeatedly got an exception that some class it was trying to access needed a parameterless constructor when I gave it a DbContext and Entity. (I'd temporarily added a constructor to the DbConext and Controller...)